# How to convert Hive schema to Bigquery schema using Python?

Tags: python, arrays, hive, google-bigquery, schema

**What i get from api:**

```
"name":"reports"
"col_type":"array<struct<imageUrl:string,reportedBy:string>>"
```

So in hive schema I got:

```
reports array<struct<imageUrl:string,reportedBy:string>>
```

*Note:*  I got hive array schema as string from api

**My target:**

```
bigquery.SchemaField("reports", "RECORD", mode="NULLABLE",
        fields=(
             bigquery.SchemaField('imageUrl', 'STRING'),
             bigquery.SchemaField('reportedBy', 'STRING')
               )
     )
```

*Note:* I would like to create universal code that can handle when i receive any number of struct inside of the array.

Any tips are welcome.

Comment: What API did you use to generate the schema?

Comment: It is our data catalog we page where we can check column and table details.

Comment: What i will try to do is, split col_type using "<" and try to undetstand how many struct are there inside the array and according the result I will try to split using "struct" and get its content. Any more proper idea will be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I tried creating a script that parses your input which is `reports array<struct<imageUrl:string,reportedBy:string>>`. This converts your input to a dictionary that could be used as [schema when creating a table](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/schemas#creating_a_json_schema_file). The main idea of the apporach is instead of using SchemaField(), you can create a dictionary which is much easier than creating SchemaField() objects with parameters using your example input.

NOTE: The script is only tested based on your input and it can parse more fields if added in struct<.

```
import re
from google.cloud import bigquery



def is_even(number):
    if (number % 2) == 0:
        return True
    else:
        return False

def clean_string(str_value):
    return re.sub(r'[\W_]+', '', str_value)

def convert_to_bqdict(api_string):
    """
    This only works for a struct with multiple fields
    This could give you an idea on constructing a schema dict for BigQuery
    """
    num_even = True
    main_dict = {}
    struct_dict = {}
    field_arr = []
    schema_arr = []

    # Hard coded this since not sure what the string will look like if there are more inputs
    init_struct = sample.split(' ')
    main_dict["name"] = init_struct[0]
    main_dict["type"] = "RECORD"
    main_dict["mode"] = "NULLABLE"

    cont_struct = init_struct[1].split('<')
    num_elem = len(cont_struct)

    # parse fields inside of struct<
    for i in range(0,num_elem):
        num_even = is_even(i)
        # fields are seen on even indices
        if num_even and i != 0:
            temp = list(filter(None,cont_struct[i].split(','))) # remove blank elements
            for elem in temp:
                fields = list(filter(None,elem.split(':')))

                struct_dict["name"] = clean_string(fields[0]) 
                # "type" works for STRING as of the moment refer to 
                # https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/schemas#standard_sql_data_types
                # for the accepted data types
                struct_dict["type"] = clean_string(fields[1]).upper() 
                struct_dict["mode"] = "NULLABLE" 
                
                field_arr.append(struct_dict)
                struct_dict = {}

    main_dict["fields"] = field_arr # assign dict to array of fields
    schema_arr.append(main_dict)
    
    return schema_arr

sample = "reports array<struct<imageUrl:string,reportedBy:string,newfield:bool>>"

bq_dict = convert_to_bqdict(sample)

client = bigquery.Client()
project = client.project
dataset_ref = bigquery.DatasetReference(project, '20211228')
table_ref = dataset_ref.table("20220203")
table = bigquery.Table(table_ref, schema=bq_dict)
table = client.create_table(table)
```

Output:
[image]

Comment: Thanks a lot, it works like charm. I created several tables using your script, only until the face some nested structs. Any idea about how we can transform this even convert nested record fields?

Comment: sample = "reports array<struct<orderlineid:string,ordernumber:string,price:struct<currencycode:string,value:double>,quantity:int,serialnumbers:array<string>,sku:string>>"

Comment: For this one, kindly put up another question in Stack overflow so that other members of the community can easily find answers if they had similar scenario to yours.

Comment: Thanks again for the suggestion @Anjela B:https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70981937/how-to-convert-nested-hive-query-schema-into-bigquery-schema-using-python